# Saxon throws 'top-level text node' exception for XSLT, but XML seems well-formed to me

Tags: xml, tomcat, xslt, saxon, apache-cocoon

I'm running Cocoon with Apache Tomcat 7.0.42, on Mac OSX. I'm continually getting a very strange error from Saxon. It says I have a top-level text-node in my XML. First off, I'm not sure if they mean my output xml or my xsl xml. Secondly, I believe neither has a top-level text node.

Here is the error message from the stack trace:

> net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: When 'standalone' or 'doctype-system' is specified, the document must be well-formed; but this document contains a top-level text node
>       net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.characters(XMLEmitter.java:574)
>       net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.flush(ReceivingContentHandler.java:543)

<...long stack trace...>

> org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:106)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       org.apache.cocoon.servlet.multipart.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:131)

Here is my departments_list.xsl, which imports common.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="common.xsl" />


    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <xsl:call-template name="header" />
                <xsl:call-template name="footer" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my common.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:template name="header">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <head>
        <title> 
        <!-- static for now. Can use parameters though. -->
    Harvard University FAS Course Catalog
        </title>
        <xsl:call-template name="css" />
        <xsl:call-template name="js" />
    </head>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="footer">
    <div id="footer">
        <hr />
        <ul>
            <li>Web Development with XML</li>
            <li>Bret Fontecchio</li>
            <li>Fall 2013</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="css">
    <style type="text/css">
        <!-- CSS Rules -->
    </style>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="js">
    <!-- use this template to add js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foobar.js"></script>
-->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please provide input XML.

Comment: And also please provide the Java code that invoked Saxon, along with the COMPLETE stacktrace and indicate which statement in your code threw the exception.

Comment: Both excellent comments. Also check that you are not moving files across file systems and getting a byte order mark in the front of some of the files. I have had similar issues and this was the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I think I figured it out. The html head opened inside the body tag and for some reason this threw a really irrelevant sounding error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, and I'm pretty sure that your explanation (putting the head inside the body) is irrelevant.

It's a serialization error; what it means is that when either doctype-system or standalone is requested as a serialization option, the output must be a well-formed document; it can't have top-level text outside any element.

Firstly, I don't believe the error can occur unless one of the serialization parameters "standalone" or "doctype-system" is specified. It's possible these are being set from the calling application rather than from the stylesheet code.

Secondly, I'm pretty sure the error can only occur if you write text to the output file when there is no open element.

So there's something going on that you haven't told us about.